# How to use JSoup to get web page by sending a specific date?

Tags: java, jsoup

I am not good at web communication with java.
I am tring to use JSoup to connect a web page            http://www.taifex.com.tw/chinese/3/3_2_2.asp by sending a new date 2015/08/27. 
But it always get the web page about 2015/08/28.

Here is my code.

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.taifex.com.tw/chinese/3/3_2_2.asp")
                .data("3_2_2_getcontract.asp?date1=2015/08/27 data2=", "false").get();
Element x = doc.select("h3:matches(日期)").first();
System.out.print(x.text());
```

I hope the line `System.out.print(x.text());`
should print 2015/08/27.
Can anyone help me to solve this problem? many thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. But it is not work. My code is rewrite as below
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.taifex.com.tw/chinese/3/3_2_2.asp")
                     .data("3_2_2_getcontract.asp?date1=2015//08//27 data2=", "false").post();

It is still not work. 
Can you give me an example? Many thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am appreciate. 
I use code as below, it still returns the date: 2015/08/28
   
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.taifex.com.tw/chinese/3/3_2_2.asp")
                     .data("datestart=2015//08//27","false").post();

Comment: Wow, It seems a difficult mission for me to get the web page with date 2015/8/27. 
Do you mean JSoup cannot be used to solve this problem?

Comment: I am so sorry, I don't know how to find the other fields that should be send. But, now, the problem is solved. thank you, again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Document doc = Jsoup
        .connect("http://www.taifex.com.tw/chinese/3/3_2_2.asp")
        .data("qtype","")
        .data("commodity_id","TXO")
        .data("commodity_id2","")
        .data("goday","")
        .data("dateaddcnt","0")
        .data("DATA_DATE_Y","2015")
        .data("DATA_DATE_M","8")
        .data("DATA_DATE_D","27")
        .data("syear","2015")
        .data("smonth","8")
        .data("sday","27")
        .post();

Element x = doc.select("h3:matches(日期)").first();
System.out.print(x.text());
```

There is a lot happening in the background by hidden inputs etc. 
Basically what you need is to find the elements sent when you press the orange button. What happens when you press that is a `POST` request to the same url with the above values filled.